# Gremlin query using mergeV, sideeffects, inject

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am struggling with a complex gremlin query and need help.

(I used the provided queries by Taylor to create the demo model)

The data model consists of orders which have products attached to it. The products are identified by their sku number.
These products are now packed into boxes (I have added a packet number to visualize the upserting effect, but in reality there will not be any property in the box nodes).

The input for the query should be:

A - order number (the order number can already exist or will be a new one)

B - a list of sku numbers which will be packed in a new box (the products with the sku number can already exist or will be new ones)

The query should do:

1. Search for the order by the given number A, and create a new one if it is not found.
2. Search for products with the sku numbers that are in the given list B or create the missing products.
3. Remove all edges of these products that are already linked to a box (It is no longer packed in this box)
4. Create a new box
5. Attach all found and created products from step 2 to the box created in step 4)
6. Remove boxes that have no packed products (They are no longer needed)

Based on the sample provided by Taylor the effects are as described:

Before:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osqwt.jpg)

The product "10000" is packed in box 1.
The products "10002" and "10005" are packed in box 2.
The products with the numbers "10001", "10003" and "10004" are packed in box 3.

The query should process order "ABC01" and products "10000", "10002" and "10006".

After:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZFnM.jpg)

A new box 4 is created.
The products "10000" and "10002" are removed from their originally assigned boxes 1 and 2.
A new product "10006" is created.
The processed products are linked to the new box.
Box 1 is deleted, because no product is referring to this box anymore.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Created an example graph here for further demonstration:

```
g.addV('Order').property(id,'order001').as('o1').
addV('Product').property(id,'product10000').property('sku','10000').as('p0').
addV('Product').property(id,'product10001').property('sku','10001').as('p1').
addV('Product').property(id,'product10002').property('sku','10002').as('p2').
addV('Product').property(id,'product10003').property('sku','10003').as('p3').
addV('Product').property(id,'product10004').property('sku','10004').as('p4').
addV('Product').property(id,'product10005').property('sku','10005').as('p5').
addV('Box').property(id,'box001').as('b1').
addV('Box').property(id,'box002').as('b2').
addV('Box').property(id,'box003').as('b3').
addE('ordered').from('o1').to('p0').
addE('ordered').from('o1').to('p1').
addE('ordered').from('o1').to('p2').
addE('ordered').from('o1').to('p3').
addE('ordered').from('o1').to('p4').
addE('ordered').from('o1').to('p5').
addE('packed').from('p0').to('b1').
addE('packed').from('p2').to('b2').
addE('packed').from('p5').to('b2').
addE('packed').from('p1').to('b3').
addE('packed').from('p3').to('b3').
addE('packed').from('p4').to('b3')
```

First off, you may want to consider some of the implications of this data model. Is the intent to create a new product vertex for each order?  If not, you could require a lot of duplication of product vertices.  For example, if I created another order (called order002) that also contained product 10000 and 10001, how would I know which box associated with those two products was associated with which order?

```
g.addV('Order').property(id,'order002').as('o2').
addV('Box').property(id,'box004').as('b4').
addE('ordered').from('o2').to(V('product10000')).
addE('ordered').from('o2').to(V('product10001')).
addE('packed').from(V('product10000')).to('b4').
addE('packed').from(V('product10001')).to('b4')
```

[image]

If you're going to continue to use this model, you may likely want to include an edge from an order to a box to ensure that you know which boxes are associated to which orders.

I'll try to see if I can come up with a mergeV/E query that can do what you're asking. What programming language are you using to build your application?

Comment: Thanks Taylor, I will supply a before/after diagram and better requirements soon to further clarify the needs (I am heavily involved in an other project at the moment).